# How to inject a component in between a markdown content generated by ngx-markdown

Tags: angular, markdown

I am trying to add customized callouts and code blocks like the following to my documentation:

[image: Example Image]

Is it possible to inject a component for the code block or callout directly within the markdown content by specifying a identifier in the markdown?

I have not been able to find any solutions related to this so far. Or is my approach completely wrong?